# Final and Immutable Variable Changes in Java

Tags: java, variables, immutability, final

I have a Path class which I think is immutable. In another class called Test, I have a      final reference to an object of Path.

Yet, in between the constructor and the getter method, the Path object changes even though it is immutable and the reference is final. I know this because the length of the int array node in Path changes from the constructor to the getter. It seems as it the object is a completly different one altogether.

My program is multi-threaded but I've tried it with a single thread and that didn't resolve the problem.

Here is the immutable Path class

```
public class Path implements Iterable<Point> {

private final int[] nodes;
private final double distance;

    public Path(Scenario scenario, int gateway, int sensor){
        this.scenario = scenario;
        nodes = new int[2];

        nodes[1] = -gateway - 1;
        nodes[0] = sensor;

        distance = scenario.DISTANCE_GATEWAY_SENSOR[gateway][sensor];
    }

    public Path(Path base, int newSensor){
        scenario = base.scenario;

        //Copy the old path. These are rigid structures so that we do not need to deep copy
        nodes = new int[base.nodes.length + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < base.nodes.length; i++)
                nodes[i + 1] = base.nodes[i];

        nodes[0] = newSensor;
        distance = base.distance + scenario.DISTANCE_SENSOR_SENSOR[newSensor][nodes[1]];
    }

    public Path(Scenario scenario, int[] nodes, boolean isSensor, double distance){
        this.scenario = scenario;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.nodes = Arrays.copyOf(nodes, nodes.length);

        if(!isSensor)
            for(int i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++)
                this.nodes[i] = -this.nodes[i] -1;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Point> iterator() {
        return new PointIterator();
    }

    public class PointIterator implements Iterator<Point>{

        private int next = -1;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return next + 1 < nodes.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Point next() {
            int p = nodes[++next];
            if(p >= 0)
                return scenario.SENSOR_LOCATION[p];
            return scenario.CS_LOCATION[-p - 1];
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new IllegalAccessError("This method is not    supported");
        }

    }

}
```

and here is the Test class (with a final reference to the Path class)

```
public class Test {

    private final Path gatewayTour;

    public Test(Scenario scenario, boolean[] chosenGateway){
        distanceFitness = 0;
        Point current = scenario.SINK_LOCATION;
        boolean visited[] = new boolean[scenario.CONFIG.NUM_CS];
        int nextGateway;

        LinkedList<Integer> order = new LinkedList<>();

        do {
            double minimumDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            nextGateway = -1;
            for(int i = 0; i < scenario.CONFIG.NUM_CS; i++)
                if(!visited[i] && CHOSEN_GATEWAYS[i] && scenario.CS_LOCATION[i].isCloserThan(minimumDistance, current)) {
                    nextGateway = i;
                    minimumDistance = scenario.CS_LOCATION[i].distance(current);
                }

            if(nextGateway >= 0) {
                distanceFitness += minimumDistance;
                visited[nextGateway] = true;
                order.add(nextGateway);
                current = scenario.CS_LOCATION[nextGateway];
            }
        } while(nextGateway >= 0);

        int path[] = new int[order.size()];
        Iterator<Integer> it = order.iterator();
        for(int i = 0; i < order.size(); i++)
            path[i] = it.next().intValue();

        gatewayTour = new Path(scenario, path, false, distanceFitness);
    }

    public Path getGatewayTour(){
        //Here, the gatewayTour object has changed and does not have the same content as in the constructor
        return gatewayTour;
    }
 }
```

Is there anything in my program that permits the object to change? I'll be more precise: is there anything that woud permit the int array "nodes" in Path class to change length? Because this is the real problem.

[EDIT]: My test was flawed, which led me to believe that the value of my 'nodes' array changed. Thanks to all who pointed flaws or possible improvements in my code.

I'll accept the answer of AlexR because he pointed out that one could change individual elements in a final array; something I didn't know and that help resolve the problem.

Comment: Can you show your `//Some constructors here to initialize the variables` please?

Comment: BTW, `.remove()` should throw `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: You can change the contents of final containers but not de-reference or re-reference it, can we see the constructors and getters?

Comment: Please edit your code to show us the whole Test class, because that's where the bug is.

Comment: Look at my answer: your class is not immutable, in fact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Word `final` means that the reference marked with this word cannot be changed. It does not mean that the referenced object cannot be changed.

This means that there is no problem to change the instance of `Path` by changing its fields. Yes, you are right, your fields are final too. But let's examine them:

```
private final int[] nodes;
private final double distance;
private final Scenario scenario;
```

`distance` is a primitive, so it indeed cannot be changed once assigned during initialization. `nodes` is an array, i.e. object. The array itself cannot be changed, i.e. the reference refers to the same array. However you can change elements of the array.

`scenario` is object too. You have not sent the class `Scenario` here, but again if fields of this class can be changed this object can be changed.

Comment: Scenario is irrelevent in this case. I do not use it for the computation of anything. I have remove it from the example code

Comment: The nodes variable changes length. This is what is weird.

Comment: Certainly there are arrays in `Scenario` that are mutable.

Comment: Actually, there are. But the length of the nodes variable changes (and this is the part that screws up my program). Okay. Maybe the Path class is not completly immutable but there is no way that the scenario variable can change the length of the final array 'nodes' in the Path class and it happens.

Answer (score 2):

```
private final int[] nodes;
```

Is still mutable, assuming your constructor simply copies the array reference.

```
public Path(int[] nodes, double distance) {
    this.node = nodes;
    this.distance = distance;
}
```

This is because `Path`'s `nodes` is still pointing to the instance that was passed in. If that instance changes, then your `Path`'s state has changed.

One solution is to make a copy of `node` in the constructor (using `System.arraycopy`).

Answer (score 0):

To be sure the answer is correct we need to see more code; it's not clear what is being changed where. However, if the idea is to *guarantee* that `nodes` is unmodifiable, a primitive array (final or not) will not work. Something more like

```
private final List<Integer> nodes;


public Path(Integer[] array /* note boxed as Integer */) {
     nodes = java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(
       java.util.Arrays.asList(array));
     /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: OP wants to store an array, however... An `Array.copy()` will do nicely. Also, OP never returns the array directly AFAICS

Comment: @fge, Very possible. I was working from the description where he seemed to want a completely _immutable_ object, rather than seeing how he used it in code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here!

```
public Path(Scenario scenario, int[] nodes, boolean isSensor, double distance){
    this.scenario = scenario;
    this.distance = distance;
    this.nodes = nodes;
```

You copy the **nodes array reference**.

Use:

```
this.nodes = Arrays.copy(nodes, 0, nodes.length);
```

If you modify the array, changes will be reflected into `Path`! Similarly, if you modify the array in the constructor, changes will be reflected to the caller...

As such, your class is NOT immutable at the moment. Also, "real" (to my sense) immutable classes are `final` themselves.